# Error on pass template argument through function

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits

I write some utility to traits the return type of a function As the code shown. why the traits can't work after pass the function into traits function?
Thanks for your great help.

```cpp
template <class> 
struct FunctionHelper;

template <class R, class... ArgsT> 
struct FunctionHelper<R(ArgsT...)> {
  typedef R type;
};

template <class R, class... ArgsT> 
struct FunctionHelper<R *(ArgsT...)> {
  typedef R type;
};

int sum(int a, int b);
int *sum1(int a, int b);

template <class Func> 
void traits(Func func) {
  typename FunctionHelper<Func>::type value;
}

int main() {
  traits(sum);     // Here is error. error C2027: use of undefined type
  traits<decltype(sum)>(sum);  // Here works fine
  FunctionHelper<decltype(sum)>::type value; // Here works fine
}
```

The error message in MSVS 14.1 shows below

```
[build] E:\source\cpp\function_traits\main.cpp(17,34): error C2027: use of undefined type 'FunctionHelper<Func>' [E:\source\cpp\function_traits\build\func_traits.vcxproj]
[build]           with
[build]           [
[build]               Func=int (__cdecl *)(int,int)
[build]           ]
[build] E:\source\cpp\function_traits\main.cpp(17): message : see declaration of 'FunctionHelper<Func>' [E:\source\cpp\function_traits\build\func_traits.vcxproj]
[build]           with
[build]           [
[build]               Func=int (__cdecl *)(int,int)
[build]           ]
[build] E:\source\cpp\function_traits\main.cpp(21): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'void traits<int(__cdecl *)(int,int)>(Func)' being compiled [E:\source\cpp\function_traits\build\func_traits.vcxproj]
[build]           with
[build]           [
[build]               Func=int (__cdecl *)(int,int)
[build]           ]
[build] E:\source\cpp\function_traits\main.cpp(17,1): error C2065: 'type': undeclared identifier [E:\source\cpp\function_traits\build\func_traits.vcxproj]
[build] E:\source\cpp\function_traits\main.cpp(17,39): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'value' [E:\source\cpp\function_traits\build\func_traits.vcxproj]
[build] E:\source\cpp\function_traits\main.cpp(17,39): error C2065: 'value': undeclared identifier [E:\source\cpp\function_traits\build\func_traits.vcxproj]
```

Comment: typo: The type of the function pointer is `R (*)(ArgsT...)` not `R*(ArgsT...)`

Comment: and `FunctionHelper<Func>::type value;` needs `typename`, though you might get away without

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The second specialization means the return type is a pointer.

Comment: I have added `typename`, but the error is still there

Comment: please include the complete error message in the question. It holds important information. If you don't understand it thats no problem, but reading and explaining the error would be part of an answer

Comment: OK, I will add the error message below

Comment: there is actually a standard implementation of this. You have an odd syntax of templates.. neither specialization nor generic.

Comment: @ZhangYifan you cannot pass function as an argument, only a pointer to a function. Thus, when you call `traits(sum)`, `Func` is deduced to a pointer. But your `FunctionHelper` only handles pure function types, hence the error.

Comment: thanks. i will try use right–value refrence later.

Comment: @yeputons _"you cannot pass function as an argument, only a pointer to a function"_: why does `traits<decltype(sum)>(sum)` compile, then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments,

```
template <class R, class... ArgsT> 
struct FunctionHelper<R *(ArgsT...)> {
  typedef R type;
};
```

specializes `FunctionHelper` for a function returning a pointer, not for a
function pointer.

As for

```
traits(sum);     // Here is error. error C2027: use of undefined type
```

I suggest you have a look at [Template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction).

Since your parameter `func` is not a reference type, here:

```
template <class Func> 
void traits(Func func) {
  typename FunctionHelper<Func>::type value;
}
```

The following rule applies:

> Before deduction begins, the following adjustments to **P** and **A** are made:
>
> 1. If **P** is not a reference type,
>
>    a. [...]
>
>    b. otherwise, if **A** is a function type, **A** is replaced by the pointer type obtained from function-to-pointer conversion;

```
template<class T>
void f(T);
 
// ...
 
void b(int);
f(b); // P = T, A = void(int), adjusted to void(*)(int): deduced T = void(*)(int)
```

So, your `Func` type is deduced as `int(*)(int,int)` and compilation fails because there's no specialization of `FunctionHelper` for a function pointer.

You may get you behavior you expect by changing `traits` to

```
template <class Func>
void traits(Func const& func) {
    typename FunctionHelper<Func>::type value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It works fine.

Comment: Hi @ZhangYifan if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.